How does philosophy of religion deal with the fact that there are so many incompatible views out there?
If there is something to the "spiritual realm", at least from a philosophical perspective, how do philosophers of religion handle the existence of so many incompatible "revelations" across human history without resorting to special pleading?
It seems that if we take each religion seriously, we are left with a study of sociology/anthropology vs actual metaphysics etc

My recommendation would be to focus on the commonalities, and treat the differences as interesting alternatives to be explored. Philosophy can explore the implications of assumptions; it can't tell you which assumptions are correct. That becomes a judgment call. So skip the revelations and focus on the teachings, understanding them as human attempts to understand The Ultimate Question Of Life, The Universe, And Everything despite our having only an ant's eye view of it.

@keshlam - I think that is a great suggestion. Too bad some apologists and philosophers don't see all religions as equally valid/invalid. \

As a variant of @keshlam suggestion: Ramana Maharshi was asked something about the more iffy parts of Hinduism such as caste. His reply: "The essence of the Veda is atma; everything else is arthavada — auxiliary argument. Keep to the point, ignore the rest." The word atma can be rendered here as Oneness of All; it's more idiomatic rendering is simply 'God'

Similar to zoology: it is not aimed to assess which is the "right" animal.

@MauroALLEGRANZA OTOH, the platypus is objectively "wrong".

Fair point, and it's a good answer.  I will delete my earlier comment, as well as this one...

The philosophy of religion is a secular appraisal of religious traditions, not an attempt to sort out the various metaphysical approaches conveyed by those religions. That is, the philosophy of religion does not engage in a normative approach, nor does it endorse religion; rather, it seeks to understand religion in a cross-comparative manner. From the SEP's article Philosophy of Religion:

Philosophy of religion is the philosophical examination of the themes and concepts involved in religious traditions as well as the broader philosophical task of reflecting on matters of religious significance including the nature of religion itself, alternative concepts of God or ultimate reality, and the religious significance of general features of the cosmos (e.g., the laws of nature, the emergence of consciousness) and of historical events (e.g., the 1755 Lisbon Earthquake, the Holocaust). Philosophy of religion also includes the investigation and assessment of worldviews (such as secular naturalism) that are alternatives to religious worldviews. Philosophy of religion involves all the main areas of philosophy: metaphysics, epistemology, value theory (including moral theory and applied ethics), philosophy of language, science, history, politics, art, and so on. Section 1 offers an overview of the field and its significance, with subsequent sections covering developments in the field since the mid-twentieth century. These sections address philosophy of religion as practiced primarily (but not exclusively) in departments of philosophy and religious studies that are in the broadly analytic tradition. The entry gives significant attention to theism, but it concludes with highlighting the increasing breadth of the field, as more traditions outside the Abrahamic faiths (Judaism, Christianity, and Islam) have become the focus of important philosophical work.

In this way, philosophy of religion is a lot like anthropology which seeks to understand human cultures on their own terms, but does not endorse cultures. Thus, religions are viewed through the working lens of a philosopher, and not a theological lens per se. A good introduction is Philosophy of Religion: A Very Short Introduction by Tim Bayne.

What you call secular appraisal is better called etic mode. Equally valid is the complementary emic mode — Join the religion as prerequisite to studying it. This usage is common in anthropology — stay with the tribe under study, linguistics — learn to speak the language on a native style  first etc

I'm not sure that a philosopher of religion need necessarily be an insider or an outsider. For instance, I believe that a philosopher of religion who is Christian would necessarily approach an examination of Christianity from the emic perspective, but an atheist would engage it from an etic perspective. What they would have in common is that they would rely on contemporary secular philosophical language as opposed to approach the material as a Christian theologian.

But other than the book I listed, I don't have much interest or knowledge of the material

A philosopher of religion who is Christian would necessarily approach an examination of Christianity from the emic perspective, but an atheist would engage it from an etic perspective Then is there any meeting point? If the Christian philosopher's central claim is not exterior socalled truth-claims like virgin birth resurrection etc but just a personal experiential credo — Those who take refuge in JC have an end to their sufferings And the atheist refuses to try where is the common ground for dialogue? (JFTR Not disputing that emic inherently can't be impartial)

@Rushi The two can disagree on situating an understanding of Christianity in a larger worldview, but still agree on facts and details. In fact, two intelligent philosophers would like approach the other's position acknowledging the logical consequence of the arguments without having to agree on the premises.

That presumes that "facts and details" signify anything. Sure they do in science engineering law etc. But in religion??? If someone repeats a mantra 10,000 times and finds his health improved, what/why shoukd he care about the ontic veracity of the deity his mantra supposedly invokes? (Any more than say we question the details of doctor prescriptions)

@Rushi But the point is not agreeing on the truth of the religion, it's agreeing on the effect of the religion on society. Even if you disagree on whether effects are positive or negative, you can still observe its effects without prejudice.

@Graham ...observe without prejudice You really believe that?  I mean seriously — We are right now in near WWIII scenario... Why?

@Rushi I think you might want to reconsider the world is on the brink of a world war, or that facts and details are irrelevant.

Now now @JD! I questioned whether facts and details signify in religion. Immediately after acknowledging that they do matter in law, science, engineering... Needless to say (geo)politics would go with the rest, not religion. My central point is Truth Claims are not the stuff of religion. Of course exceptions can be found eg. Evangelicals who will thump their bible onto you if you don't make some trite declaration of allegiance acknowledging some truth claim like resurrection etc. These are exceptions

@Rushi "Truth Claims are not the stuff of religion" Raised as a Lutheran, I can tell you that every Sunday is nothing more than affirming both the truth of the Gospels. The Nicene creed is list of truthful assertions. The Book of Concord is a theological defense of religious truths. :D Why you would claim religion doesn't deal in claims of truth is perplexing. :D

Lutheran — in general protestant/ /evangelical — are the exception. (My  condolences for a bruising youth) I was in a Catholic (jesuit) school, college — and I can't remember any reverend ever bamboozling anyone toward some belief. Of course all religions have truth claims — dozens of major ones, and zillions of minor ones. My claim is that a commitment to the religion is not coincident with believing the truth claims. Consider the case of Jewish atheists. Note this is not just the case of lapsed jews but strict orthodox, observant, atheist jews


How do philosophers of religion handle the existence of so many incompatible "revelations" across human history without resorting to special pleading? 
It seems that if we take each religion seriously, we are left with a study of sociology/anthropology vs actual metaphysics etc

(1) One possible answer is silence. As in


Whereof one cannot speak, thereof one must be silent." (Tractatus.)


"Must" does not mean "ought" here, but inevitable failure to express even if one would try to do so. This could be seen as a radicalization of Kant's transcendental idealism. The "thing-in-itself" ("the world"), the "I" (the epistemic subject), "God" (the feeling of the world as determinate whole) -- which to Kant are all still given on the epistemic horizon, seem to fade away on that horizon.
(2) Philosophy of religions can also proceed by using the same suspension of judgment -- the sceptical epoche -- that is used in the psychology and sociology of religion. Instead of asking whether religious beliefs are true, one brackets that question, and only considers beliefs as data points in their relation to actions. (A pragmatist might say, that that is the only way to make sense of any truth claims anyway.)
(3) I only know one philosopher in the last century who did tackle the truth question head on and did not resort to "special pleading". This is A. N. Whitehead, in Religion in the Making. The book is about a century old now, and may be a bit too romantic and simple, but it's original and intellectually honest. In the lecture about "Dogma" and "God", he writes:

To-day there is but one religious dogma in debate: What do you mean by "God"?

He then lists the three main answers given by various traditions:

The East-Asian concept of an impersonal order to which the world conforms; "the self-ordering of the world, not the world obeying an imposed rule"; "the extreme doctrine of immanence".
The Semitic concept of "a definite personal, individual entity", creator and judge of the world; "the extreme doctrine of transcendence".
The Pantheistic concept in which "the actual world's only reality is God's reality"; "the extreme doctrine of monism".

A comment that I found particularly remarkable was this:

... the various doctrines of God have not suffered chiefly from their complexity. They have represented extremes of simplicity. ... The three extremes of simple notions should not represent in our eyes multually exclusive concepts, from among which we are to choose one and reject the others. ... [R]econcilement of these contrary concepts must be sought in a more searching analysis of the meaning of the terms in which they are phrased.


This is a quite good philosophical answer. It appears though that the question is asking for a more societal viewpoint. In short: How philosophy of religion should/can be practiced vs. How it is actually done in most cases

@Rushi - Not sure what to say to that. I think the three approaches that I pointed at are all interesting and valid approaches. Personally I favor a purely pragmatist stance.

The key term you are probably looking for is religious pluralism.

Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_pluralism
SEP: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/religious-pluralism/
IEP: https://iep.utm.edu/rel-plur/

The specific problem you raise about incompatible views has actually been used as an argument against God's existence, see Argument from inconsistent revelations:

The Argument from inconsistent revelations (also known as Avoiding the wrong hell problem) is an argument that says that God probably does not exist. There are many religions which are based on revelations. The problem with these revelations is that they contradict each other. A person must either accept or reject at least one of these revelations in order to be part of a religious group. That way, accepting one means rejecting some (if not all) of the others. Unless the revelation is personal, the follower must to some extent rely on the judgment or the stories of others. Assuming the revelation is personal, the follower is still ignoring the revelations of those before him.
Christians believe that Jesus is the savior of the world and the son of God; Jews believe just as strongly that he is not. Similarly, Muslims believe that the Qur'an was divinely authored, while Jews and Christians do not. There are many examples of such contrasting views. Positions where one religion contradicts another, or where one group of people contradicts another are common. There are many denominations in Christianity who do not agree about many things.

Regarding your specific question about possible responses to the existence of religious pluralism from a philosophical perspective, the IEP has a section that directly answers this question:

1. Categories of Responses to Diversity
There are a number of different ways that philosophers and theologians
have grouped various accounts of religious diversity. One of the most
commonly adopted strategies – and the one that will be used in the
following discussion – is the threefold division first introduced by
Alan Race (1983): exclusivist, inclusivist, and pluralist. Exclusivist
positions maintain that only one set of belief claims or practices can
ultimately be true or correct (in most cases, those of the one holding
the position). A Christian exclusivist would therefore hold that the
beliefs of non-Christians (and perhaps even Christians of other
denominations) are in some way flawed, if not wholly false; or that
non-Christian religious practices are not ultimately efficacious – at
least, to the extent that non-Christian beliefs and practices depart
from or conflict with those defended by the Christian exclusivist.
Pluralist positions, in contrast, argue that more than one set of
beliefs or practices can be, at least partially and perhaps wholly,
true or correct simultaneously – or, that all beliefs intended to be
understood in a realist fashion are false. Inclusivist positions
occupy a middle ground between exclusivism and pluralism, insofar as
they recognize the possibility that more than one religious tradition
can contain elements that are true or efficacious, while at the same
time hold that only one tradition expresses ultimate religious truth
most completely. As McKim (2012) expresses it, inclusivists grant that
many (perhaps all) religious traditions do well in regards to truth or
salvation, but that one tradition does better than others by more
accurately describing objects of belief or mechanisms of salvation. A
Christian inclusivist might claim that those who live good lives but
remain non-Christians may still achieve salvation, but that such
salvation is nevertheless still achieved through Jesus Christ.
Inclusivism thus may be understood as a more charitable variety of
exclusivism, though exclusivists can also treat it as pluralism by
another name. In addition, it is worth noting that exclusivist,
inclusivist, or pluralist arguments about beliefs are sometimes
presented separately from those about salvific practice and that
consequently one approach to diversity of belief does not necessarily
imply the same approach to diversity of practice, or vice versa.
There remain a few other possible positions outside of exclusivism,
inclusivism, and pluralism that are worth mentioning briefly, though
two of these are not commonly treated as sophisticated options in
philosophical discussions of religious diversity. The first of these
two is relativism: the view that the truth of beliefs or the efficacy
of practices are wholly dependent on the perspective of the religious
individual and her cultural environment. In contrast to the pluralist
position, that of the relativist seems necessarily to imply an
anti-realist theory of religious truth, which would deflate the
significance of religious pluralism as a philosophical and theological
issue since religious truth claims could only be upheld or defeated
within the context of their own traditions. The second, which would
have similar consequences, is the position that no positive religious
beliefs are true in any sense, even the relativist ones, and no
religious practices are efficacious (at least not according to their
own terms). In this case, which may be termed strong anti-realism,
religious diversity remains at most a sociological, psychological, or
historical topic. It is perhaps not surprising, then, that serious
philosophical approaches to religious diversity tend not to adopt
either of these positions but rather to treat diverse religious
traditions as at least possibly having some positive relationship to
an ultimate reality. Another position, that of skepticism, seems to
entertain this possibility insofar as it concedes that some set of
religious claims may be true. However, since this position contends
that, given the extent of religious diversity and disagreement, no one
is ever justified in making such claims, this position will not be
considered in detail here (for a contemporary defense of the skeptical
position, see Feldman 2007).

